# Unable to calculate values in a joined table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.4

Using Arc 10.4.1, I have joined a geodatabase feature class table to a standalone geodatabase attribute table.  This is a many:1 join (standalone attribute table:feature class).  After making the join, I need to do a series of queries on the standalone attribute table, then calculate a field in the feature class table.  Because of this many:1 situation, I am forced to join the feature class table to the standalone attribute table, rather than joining the standalone attribute table to the feature class table.

However, when I try to change values in the joined (feature class) table, the field calculator is greyed out. Sure enough, the Arc Help documentation states:

> "You can only calculate values for fields in the origin table."

But I could swear that I've successfully used the field calculator on a joined table in the past (Arc 9.x, methinks).

Is there a way to create calculations on joined fields?

Comment: What about joining the fc to the standalone table?

Comment: Reverse the join.  You can only edit the parent table, not the joined table.  As far as I can recall this has always been the case.

Comment: @Midavalo I cannot reverse the join because of a many:1 situation.  I've edited the original question to include this.

Comment: Start editing the table and then calculate the fields. I think that has worked for me in the past. Additionally, before the join, make a new field for the calculations, then joins and do the calculations in the new field

Comment: @TvsGis you are correct!  Please feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: For future reference, I might also add that creating a relate instead of a join works for the many:1 situations such as I described in my question.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @tsvgis:

> Start editing the table and then calculate the fields. I think that
>   has worked for me in the past. Additionally, before the join, make a
>   new field for the calculations, then joins and do the calculations in
>   the new field

Comment: @TsvGis Well, here I am a year later after an upgrade to 10.5.1, and the problem has returned: the Field Calculator is grayed out for all fields in a Join table (it is not grayed out for the Origin table fields).  It doesn't matter whether I start editing the Join table before or after making the join - the Field Calculator is not available to make edits in the Join table.  Huh?

Answer (score 0):

I found your post searching for my own solution to this problem in 10.6.1. But I realized the issue was that I had joined one table to another table that also had a join with a different table, which was making the field calculator button grey out.

So it went like this:

- Table A was joined to Table B creating Table A/B
- Table A/B joined to Table C - buttons greyed out
- Table A OR Table B joined to Table C - buttons function

This may not be what's causing it for you, but if not you, maybe it will help someone else.